# RegEx does not get executed in Gulp.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, gulp, gulp-replace

I was wondering why this regular expression doesn't get executed in Gulp task. 'replace' task uses gulp-replace.

RegEx

```
/url\((?:["'])?(?:\/?[a-zA-Z0-9])*\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\.(png|jpeg|jpg))(?:["'])?\)/g
```

Actual Gulp task

```
gulp.task('process-sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/html/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass.sync())
        .pipe(replace(/url\((?:["'])?(?:\/?[a-zA-Z0-9])*\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\.(png|jpeg|jpg))(?:["'])?\)/g, 'url(/src/assets/$1)'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
            path.dirname += '/';
            path.basename = 'bundle.min';
            path.extname = '.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./builds/development'));
});
```

All help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When I used .pipe(replace(/url/g, 'foo')) for testing purposes it worked. The problem is only with the actual RegEx. I checked it at https://regex101.com where it works. I'm not very familiar with regular expressions so I'm sorry if I'm missing only something minor.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/79bubZ/2